# Moving two forms together without changing the positions (behind or front) of the two forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am quite new to C#. Recently, I got stuck on a problem which is that I want to move two different forms together.

In more detail,

One big form (i.e. something as parent window) popups a small form.

What I want to do is to move these two forms at the same time by moving the parent window.

And, now I am creating the children (small) form by "Show()" method of Form.
The problem is that if I click the parent form, a small form goes behind the parent form (i.e. bigger form).

I know this is what should happen. However, I want to move these two forms by moving the bigger form while keeping the small form is front.

I also considered using "ShowDialog()". But, this prevent me from moving the bigger parent. I cannot event touch the parent window.

Comment: try this.
frmChild.Show(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the child form's Owner property to the parent form:

```
this.childForm = new ChildFormClass();
child.Owner = this;
viewForm.ShowDialog();
//Can also be called like this instead of setting Owner property:
//viewForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx

This way, the child form will never be shown behind the parent.

EDIT:

To move both forms together, simply handle the parent's form Move event:

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point p = this.PointToScreen(new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y));
    this.childForm.Location = p; //childForm needs to be a class member
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I just realized you also wanted to know about moving the child form with the parent. I'll update my example.

Comment: Yeah, But, I think I can do that part. Keeping child form front was tricky for me.