# Move 2 windows forms together unless the second form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

So 2 days ago I asked how to move 2 forms together, I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415954/11867443) which really helped me.
 But now I would like to know **how to move the first form, while the second one is minimized** (so it has to stop moving while minimized, or it will result in a crash from the second form...)**?**
I tried this:

```
private void MainForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // All open child forms to be moved
  Form[] formsToAdjust = Application
    .OpenForms
    .OfType<ChildForm>()
    .ToArray();
    FormsToAdjust formsToAdjust1 = new FormsToAdjust(); //added this

  // If the main form has been moved...
if (formsToAdjust1.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized) //and this statement as well
{
  if (m_PreviousLocation.X != int.MinValue)
    foreach (var form in formsToAdjust) //... we move all child froms aw well
      form.Location = new Point(
        form.Location.X + Location.X - m_PreviousLocation.X,
        form.Location.Y + Location.Y - m_PreviousLocation.Y
      );

  m_PreviousLocation = Location;
}
}
```

but it can't work as it will open the second form each time the main form will be moved (yes this was a stupid attempt, but I really can't manage how to go through that problem)...
So the **goal** would be to, **if the second form is minimized**, keep **being able to move the main form, without changing the location of the second one.**
Any help would be really appreciated, **I'm going to continue searching by my side** (actually searching for a while now) while waiting for a reply.
***Thanks :)***

Comment: why not check if the child form is **minimized** ? If yes, leave it!

Comment: `if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) form.Location = ...`

Comment: This is not exactly how this thing works. The Child Form(s) should subscribe to the Owner Form `Resize` and `Move` events, checking whether their `WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal` before attempting to move. Also check the `FormWindowState.Maximized` of the Owner Form and reposition accordingly (maybe inside the Owner bounds). You should show a child Form with `.Show(this)`, so a `FormWindowState.Minimized` of the Owner is irrelevant, since a Child Form will also minimize when the Owner is minimized. Or use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812831/7444103).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a *filter* with a help of `Where`: we want to move all child forms that are in `Normal` (neither `Minimized` nor `Maximized`) window state

```
Form[] formsToAdjust = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<ChildForm>()
  .Where(child => child.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
  .ToArray();
```

then business as usual:

```
  if (m_PreviousLocation.X != int.MinValue)
    foreach (var form in formsToAdjust) 
      form.Location = new Point(
        form.Location.X + Location.X - m_PreviousLocation.X,
        form.Location.Y + Location.Y - m_PreviousLocation.Y
      );

  m_PreviousLocation = Location;
```

Comment: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate?view=netframework-4.8

`Remarks
Before a form is displayed, the WindowState property is always set to FormWindowState.Normal, regardless of its initial setting. This is reflected in the Height, Left, Top, and Width property settings. If a form is hidden after it has been shown, these properties reflect the previous state until the form is shown again, regardless of any changes made to the WindowState property.`
Isn't it better to check if minimized ?

Comment: @Kaj: since we get `Application.OpenForms` so when form is *not displayed* we don't move them

Comment: I missed that :) sorry